# JSON Object to be Stored into an Array

Tags: javascript, json

I am currently trying to store JSON stringified objects into an array so I will be able to add new elements as I go along:

```
function GetAllPatients(){
var patient = null;
var patients = [];


patient = { "FirstName": "Stephanie", "Gender": "Female", "Id": "P8401", "LastName": "BARRON", "Title": "Ms", "ConsultantId": "d10", "CurrentWardAdmissionName": "Non Admitted", "DOB": "/Date(1187650800000+0100)/", "HospitalAdmissionDate": "/Date(1294848066000+0000)/", "NHSNumber": "4646399561" };


patient = { "FirstName": "Joan", "Gender": "Female", "Id": "50434619", "LastName": "SMITH", "Title": "Mrs", "ConsultantId": "d1", "CurrentWardAdmissionName": "Non Admitted", "DOB": "/Date(513039600000+0100)/", "HospitalAdmissionDate": "/Date(1332242252817+0000)/", "NHSNumber": "9999999999" };

}
```

and also a switch case getPatientFromStore(pid) function which will retrieve a record by pid

How would I go about achieving this? 
Is there any more information which I would require to help get me closer to a solution?

Basically, I'm in the middle of creating a web application which will allow offline local storage at a disconnected state, and also sync with a database on the server.

Comment: Have you tried anything else other than what you've displayed above?

Comment: you were spot on with what you have answered, thank you for that. For now i'm trying to save this to local storage which might be quite challenging

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can insert elements into an array by using `push`:

For example:

```
patients.push({
    "FirstName": "Stephanie",
    "Gender": "Female",
    "Id": "P8401",
    "LastName": "BARRON",
    "Title": "Ms",
    "ConsultantId": "d10",
    "CurrentWardAdmissionName": "Non Admitted",
    "DOB": "/Date(1187650800000+0100)/",
    "HospitalAdmissionDate": "/Date(1294848066000+0000)/",
    "NHSNumber": "4646399561"
});
```

As far as looking up by id, rather than an array, it would be better to use an associative array, like so:

```
var patients = {};
function addPatient(patient) {
    patients[patient.id] = patient;
}
```

Then in your method to return a patient given the patient's id, you can do:

```
function getPatient(id) {
    return patients[id];
}
```

This is useful if you're going to be looking up patients by their id all the time.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use multiple indexes to access the same patient.

E.g. if you wanted to use NHSNumber as well as id you could do the following in the addPatients() function:

```
var patients = { };
var nhsNumberMap = { };
function addPatient(patient) {
    patients[patient.id] = patient;
    nhsNumberMap[patient.NHSNumber] = patient;
}
```

So you could also have another function:

```
getPatientByNHSNumber(nhsNumber) {
    return nhsNumberMap[nhsNumber];
}
```